# How to make add events reflect in realtime using Angular 2 FullCalendar typescript with MongoDB

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar

I want to know how to make data reflect right away after clicking the addEvent function I made. I tried calling the getEvents I made in the constructor, but it doesn't reflect immediately unless I refresh the page

UPDATE:

event.service.ts

```
public deleteEvent(id): Observable<any> {
const headers = new Headers({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
});
const url = `${this.baseUrl}api/deleteevent/${id}`;
  return this.http.delete(url)
  .map((response: Response) => {
      console.log(response.json().data);
      return response.json();
  })
  .catch(err => {
      return Observable.throw(err);
  });
}
```

view-calendar.ts

```
deleteEvent() {
this.eventService.deleteEvent(this.id).subscribe(
  delData => {
    this.delete = delData;

    this.ucCalendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', this.delete);
    this.ucCalendar.fullCalendar('renderEvents');
  }
);
}


getAllEvents() {
// store token in variable
const data = localStorage.getItem('token');

// decode the token
const decoded = jwt.decode(data);

// store data in user
this.user = decoded.data;

this.eventService.getEvents(this.user.faculty_number).subscribe(
  eventData => {
  this.eventData = eventData;
  this.calendarOptions = {
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: false,
    selectable: true,

    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today add',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    events: eventData
  };
});
}
```

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/

Comment: @ADyson, I updated my post, could you check my error?

Comment: Please post actual code not pictures. Surely it's quicker to copy/paste anyway?? Thanks. Anyway I'm not really sure what you want me to say? What's the content of `this.delete`? I can't tell you why nothing happens if I don't know what data you passed in, and I can't see your console to see if you got any errors or not. And calling renderEvents afterwards without any arguments makes no sense, that's for adding an array of events.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just new to this hahaha. I saw the npm full calendar docs, and they used the renderEvents like that. Btw, I updated my post :) Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure they maybe didn't use https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/rerenderEvents/ or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/refetchEvents/ actually? Although in either case it's still not really necessary in this situation.

Comment: Also you still haven't told me what the content of your `this.delete` object is when you run the "renderEvent" method. That's key to the whole thing. If that isn't a valid event object then it won't add anything to the calendar.  I have to say that to me the conbination of "renderEvent" and you apearing to "delete" an event doesn't make a lot of sense on the surface -
 why are you adding to the calendar something you've deleted? Also you probably want to set the "stick" parameter to true so that it persists if the user moves between different views or date ranges before they refresh the page.

Comment: calling the this.delete object was indeed wrong, Idk why I put it up there hahahaha, anyway, I always come across an error with the 'renderEvent' that says ''Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at constructor.renderEvents (fullcalendar.js:11383)" I'll take note of the stick parameter :D

Comment: renderEvent != renderEvents - two different methods. That might be your problem. That error is about not being able to read the length of an array. renderEvents expects an array, renderEvent expects a single object. If you passed a single object to renderEvents I can see you might have a problem.

Comment: Thank you, I will check on this, will update you asap